# I had taken checkboxes for hobby in Angular 4,but I am not able to take values of it.I am getting null value

Tags: angular

I had taken checkboxes for hobby in Angular 4, but I am not able to take values of it. I am getting null value.

My code is as below :

```js
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.saveRegistrationDetail(form.value);
}

saveRegistrationDetail(emp: EmployeeDTO) {
    this._savedataservice.SaveEmpDetails(emp)
        .subscribe(data => {
            //this.resetForm();
        })
}
```

```html
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="0" checked 
        [(ngModel)]="Hobbies">Running<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="1" 
        [(ngModel)]="Hobbies">Playing<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="2" 
        [(ngModel)]="Hobbies" >Reading<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="3" 
        [(ngModel)]="Hobbies">Other<br>
</td>
```

Comment: Bhumika, you need to provide some more code so that we can see what you are doing wrong. If you are doing it for learning purpose, you can refer my git repo where  I have created some small examples. https://github.com/shashankvivek/Angular4/tree/master/Reactive_creature_form

Comment: Haven't you noticed that when you check a checkbox, all become checked? ot really surprising since they are all bound to the same property: Hobies. So cecking one checkbox sets Hobbies to true, and since all checkboxes are bound to Hobbies, all checkboxes become checked. Use a separate binding for each checkbox. And don't use `checked`: the point of truth is the model. So if the property is true, the checkbox is checked. If it's false, it's unchecked. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctd1af?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ok.Got it.Thank you.@JBNizet.